# Preview in Android Studio do not same as the one in hardware

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a ImageView as background and would like to place some widget in front of the background.

I've tried both Relative Layout and Linear Layout but still found that the layout preview in AndroidStudio is not the same as the one I deployed in my device. The device and the background image are both in 16:9, 1920x1080

- Background Resolution: 1080x1920
- Device Resolution: 1080x1920
- Activity Theme: Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Here is the layout XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chihangc.imaginecup_prel.MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/r01_main"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="New Buttonr"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="New Buttonr"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hardware Screenshot

[image: Screenshot in Hardware Device]

Android Studio Layout Preview

[image: Screenshot of the preview in Android Studio]

Comment: is your device in layout preview has the same configuration as your hardware device?

Comment: Is both also on same Android SDK API version?

Comment: @Pooya, Yes, I added by myself

Comment: @Radix, thanks. Could you explain more about how Framelayout can implement the above solution? Many thanks

Comment: @Elye Yes. I'm using API23 Android 6.0

Comment: @ChiHang: I suggest using weighting for your buttons and let the android decide its dimensions

Comment: @Pooya Thanks. Do you mean using weighting the buttons for vertical position too?

Comment: @ChiHang for vertical use wrap content and for horizontal use weighting and remove all fixed dp values

Comment: @Pooya Thanks. I know that. The main issue now I'm facing is that the vertical (y) position of those button shifted downward

Comment: @ChiHang: I think the reason is: android:layout_marginBottom="127dp" and android:layout_marginTop="500dp" you can use gravity instead

Answer (score 2):

The layout shown is pretty messy as what I could see. Several issues
  - There are some mixture of relative layout parameter in the button while it is wrap by linear layout. 
  - There are nested layer of linear layout which is unnecessary. 
  - and various hard coded value (e.g. button width.

I've made some improvement per the code. You could use this code, and readjust the top margin as you like (I put as 400dp for now), and hopefully this will provide consistent between the preview and actual device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/r01_main"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="New Buttonr"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="New Buttonr"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ideally, we shouldn't rely on the the marginTop as well. Instead separate the image into multiple images. And place the main as a top view above the bottom. Then this would have better control over the view layout across devices (which have different height).

Comment: Thank you ver much for your help. However, problem still exist. The preview and the device layout is not the same

Comment: Do you still have the `android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"` in your code?

Comment: No. I copy all your code to replace it. And it does not have any differences after adding layout_marginBottom="127dp"

Comment: What's the DPI of your emulator device, and what's your hardware device DPI?

Comment: I check that for both 1080x1090 device emulator, the Nexus 5X and Nexus 5, they both have different layout based on same .xml. Their DPI is different, and their actual device height is different (Nexus 5X is longer). Can you test that out. That's the reason using fix margin height is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check. But how can I change dpi?

Comment: You can't change the DPI. To ensure they look the same, you would need to test on the exact device with same height... If you're using Nexus 5 emulator, it should be Nexus 5 device. Apple to Apple.

Comment: Do check out https://design.google.com/devices/, Note that Nexus 5X is 411x731dp, while Nexus 5 is 360x640dp. In this case, just work on Nexus 5 version (as majority of the device is 360x640) and then later use the Dimen to specify different dp for your top margin... that will cater different height for different device length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108287/discussion-between-chihang-and-elye).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.chihangc.imaginecup_prel.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="New Buttonr" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="New Buttonr" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is the button shift downward.

Comment: Thanks, but my button still shift downward (instead of not having the same width)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the problem - vertical (y) position of those button shifted downward still can't solved

Comment: Once again I have changed my code and its works on my device fine

Comment: Once again, Thanks. Your code do not have layout_marginBottom which those buttons are not in the middle. The code still failed after I added             android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"

Comment: Ok put this android:layout_marginBottom="127dp" in the code of LinearLayout. And it works fine

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it. After adding marginBottom. It failed

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving explicit values for marginBottom you will get different output in different screen sizes. Your emulator screen size might be different from your hardware screen size. To prevent this use RelativeLayout and align the buttons accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried RelativeLayout and align the buttons with layout_marginBottom and layout_alignParentBottom. But it is still shifted downward.

Comment: If your screen sizes are different then there will be mismatch between what you seen in preview and what you see in your hardware. With different devices with different screen sizes you will get different outputs. To avoid that either you have to compute the height of the screen and set the margin accordingly or you would have to design the layout for different screen sizes.

Comment: But I have already setup a hardware profile in AndroidStudio with same resolution and screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the two screens have different size.

`android:layout_marginTop="500dp"` ensures that size of the margin will be the same regarding different densities but not ensures the position  regarding different resolutions.

You could remove the marginTop's line and align to bottom the LinearLayout.

**EDIT**
to center vertically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/r01_main" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Without using marginTop, what should I use in order to make those buttons in the middle (i mean vertical)

Comment: use `android:layout_centerVertical` for LinearLayout property.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerVertical

Comment: I tried to use a LinearLayout with specific height (150dp). Then align buttons above it. Sadly, still failed

Comment: But those buttons cannot align to different y position

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for your XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/r01_main">



<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Buttonr"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Buttonr"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> If you want to position buttons on center you could do on this way. 
>   Replace android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to
>   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical in parent layout of buttons(Linear Layout).

Comment: Thanks, but the button do not in a correct y position.

Comment: How do you want to display y position?

Comment: Refer to the question, I would like the buttons position in the middle part of the screen (Some variation of y position)

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know the status. Sorry if I could not help to reach your goal.